# Reversing digits in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to reverse the numbers in this 2D array, but I happened to be reversing only first and the last numbers.

So far I have done this, but don't know where is the mistake and how to fix it, so that every digits are being reversed, not just first and the last:

```
int [][] array = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        
        int x = 0, y = array.length - 1;
        int a = 0, b = array[y - 2].length - 1;
        int temp; 
        
        while(x < y && a < b)
        {
          temp = array[x][a]; 
          array[x][a] = array[y][b]; 
          array[y][b] = temp;
          a++; b--;
          
          if(a == 3 && b == 0)
          {
              a = 0;
              x++; y--;
          } 
        }

        
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.println(array[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: "I happened to be reversing only first and the last numbers" - I'm quite sure what you mean and you might want to provide an example. If you reverse 1,2,3 you'll get 3,2,1 which basically is swapping the first and last numbers. Besides that, I'd suggest you do it in 2 steps/loops: reverse numbers in the inner arrays separately from reserving the arrays themselves.

Comment: If I were doing this, I'd probably have separate methods for keys ops, such as `reverse(...)`, `swap(...)` etc.

Comment: @Thomas in this one for example, array is {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}. And my output becomes: 9 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1. This suggestion sounds logical. So by reversing it, i will get {{3, 2, 1}, {6, 5, 4}, {9, 8, 7}} and then i will reverse rows.

Comment: @g00se yes, exactly

Comment: So start with the easier one, `swap`

Comment: @g00se i did this, but it only swaps the first one. i tried to put a counter instead of "0", but it didn't work out as well:
      
     while(x < y)
        {
      temp = array[0][x]; 
      array[0][x] = array[0][y]; 
      array[0][y] = temp;
          
      x++; y--;
        }

Comment: *@g00se i did this, but it only swaps the first one* You're not really getting it. A `swap` method swaps two things then returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is another way that doesn't require using `Collections`.  It does use `Arrays.deepToString()` for displaying the results.

- All reverse methods shown here only require iterating across half the array.  This works whether the array has an even or odd number of values.
- first, reverse the array of arrays.
- then during that process, reverse the individual rows, going outside in as the main array is reversed.  A helper method reduces code duplication
- If the array is of odd length, call the reverse method once more on the middle array.
- This also works independent of the size of each array.

```
int[][] array = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 }, { 9 },
        { 10, 11, 12 } };

System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Now the driver code.

```
int len = array.length;
    
for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
    int[] s = array[i];
    array[i] = array[len - i - 1];
    array[len - i - 1] = s;
    reverse(array[i]);
    reverse(array[len - i - 1]);
}
if (len % 2 == 1) { 
    reverse(array[len/2]);
}   
System.out.println("After:  " + Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

output

```
Before: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9], [10, 11, 12]]
After:  [[12, 11, 10], [9], [8, 7, 6], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

The helper method.

```
public static void reverse(int[] v) {
    int len = v.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        int t = v[i];
        v[i] = v[len - i - 1];
        v[len - i - 1] = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: why len/2 in for loop?

Comment: @jjavid Good question.  Remember I am exchanging (swapping) values at both ends of the array going inward. So I only need to go halfway and still be able to index both the left and right side.  And the nice thing is that this works for odd arrays in that it won't swap the middle value with itself.

Comment: what will happen if we just write len in for loop?

Comment: In this case, it will continue to reverse, reversing what has already been reversed, thus putting the list back to its original configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve it:

```
import java.util.*;

public class main
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {           
        int [][] array = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        
        int x = 0, y = array.length - 1;
        int temp, temp2, temp3; 
        
        while(x < y)
        {
            temp = array[0][x]; 
            array[0][x] = array[0][y]; 
            array[0][y] = temp;
          
            temp2 = array[1][x]; 
            array[1][x] = array[1][y]; 
            array[1][y] = temp2;
            
            temp3 = array[2][x]; 
            array[2][x] = array[2][y]; 
            array[2][y] = temp3;
            
            x++; y--;
        }
        
        //here we get the final answer {{9, 8, 7}, {6, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}} 
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.println(array[array.length - (i + 1)][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] array = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arr =new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
            temp.add(array[i][array.length-1-j]);
        }
        arr.add(temp);
    }
    Collections.reverse(arr);
    System.out.println(arr);
}
```

and output will be,

```
[[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: So then what is the output need? here it said that reverse the array values, so reversing inner ones doesn't count?

Comment: There are four arrays in all.  So all need to be reversed.

Comment: so the output will look like this `[[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]`

Comment: I edited it to use `Collections.reverse(arr)` so the ArrayList will also be reversed :)

Comment: What does this part do?  `temp.add(array[i][array.length-1-j]);`

Comment: it will add the values in reversing order to the array list